# Study the convergence of $b_n=\sin\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}$.

Tags: calculus

If $b_n=\sin\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}$. Study the convergence of the following:

$$\sum^\infty _{n=1} (b_n-b_{n+1}) \ \ \ \sum^\infty _{n=1} b_n$$

As the first case is telescopic, I know that if one converges, the other one converges too, so, I will study $b_n-b_{n+1}=\sin\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}-\sin\sqrt{4(n+1)^2\pi^2+n+1}$

I know that $\sin A -\sin B=2\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$

So:
$$(b_n-b_{n+1})=2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}-\sqrt{4(n+1)^2\pi^2+n+1}}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}+\sqrt{4(n+1)^2\pi^2+n+1}}{2}\right)$$

I can assume that the second term is bounded, so I have to study the first one, how can I do it? Is it ok to use Taylor Expansion? If it converges, what is the result?

Comment: Convergence of $\sum b_n-b_{n+1}$ doesn't imply convergence of $\sum b_n$ i.e take $b_n=1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting $\sin(x-2n\pi)=\sin x$, so one \begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin(\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}-2n\pi)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin \bigg(\frac{n}{\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}+4n^2\pi^2}\bigg)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+\frac1n}+4n\pi^2}\bigg)\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin \bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+\frac1n}+4n\pi^2}\bigg)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+\frac1n}+4n\pi^2}}\frac{n}{\sqrt{4\pi^2+\frac1n}+4n\pi^2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{4\pi^2}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ \sin \bigg(\frac{n}{\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}+4n^2\pi^2}\bigg)\sim \frac{1}{4\pi^2n} $$
for bigg $n$. So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}$ diverges. Use the same way for $\sum(b_n-b_{n+1})$.

Comment: So the differences are $O(n^{-2})$, and the difference series converges, to complete the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: How did you get the second and third equality?

Comment: @Juju9708, see the update.

Answer (score 0):

i think one think useful to note is that:
$$n\to\infty,b_n\approx\sin(2n\pi)=0$$
in other words:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$$
we can also try taking the ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\sqrt{4(n+1)^2\pi^2+(n+1)}}{\sin\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}}\approx\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(2(n+1)\pi)}{\sin(2n\pi)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\pi\cos(2(n+1)\pi)}{2\pi\cos(2n\pi)}=1$$

through L'Hopital, when really we want this $<1$ for convergence

Comment: Actually, $b_n\approx{1\over4\pi}$, not $0$.

Comment: how did you get that @BarryCipra

Comment: $\sqrt{4n^2\pi^2+n}=2n\pi\sqrt{1+{1\over4n\pi^2}}\approx2n\pi(1+{1\over8n\pi^2})=2n\pi+{1\over4\pi}$